# Find three natural numbers $a,b,c$ such : $\begin{cases}ab=1(\mod c)\\ac=1(\mod b)\\bc=1(\mod a)\end{cases}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Question :

Find three natural numbers $a$, $b$ and $c$
such that the remainder of the euclidean division of the two numbers (of these numbers) by the third number is $1$

> Mean :

$$\begin{cases}ab\equiv 1\pmod{c}\\ac\equiv 1\pmod{b}\\bc\equiv 1\pmod{a}\end{cases}$$

I was try many numbers but no one equivalent with above conditions

So how we can find this three numbers ??

Comment: What about $2, 3, 5$?

Comment: Great.  This question has been edited 6 times now resulting in zero (or less) improvement.

Comment: @lulu can you give explain

Comment: Explain what?  You asked for an example and I gave you one...first thing I tried.

Comment: Unless one allows a solution with two of $a,b,c$ equal to 1, @Lulu's solution is the only solution to your problem.

Comment: @S.Dolan  Why is that?  I certainly expect it is so, and the supposed duplicate proves it if you require all three to be prime, but have you got a general proof?

Comment: @S.Dolan  Ah, I suppose the arguments given in the duplicate don't use primality.

Comment: @Lulu That's right. I assumed $a\ge b\ge c$ and essentially only needed to consider $c=1$ as an extra case.

Comment: @S.Dolan  Absolutely.  Thanks!